# How to create a new branch containing the difference between two other branches?

Tags: git, refactoring, git-branch, git-diff

I have a project which contains code for multiples architectures.
I copied motorola files into a different branch, I did likewise for MIPS...
Basically project is complex and not well structured and i'm trying to understand it by applying divide and conquer strategy.

I want to create a temporary branch that contains just the files that I have not yet classified and copied unto it's specific branch so not to be overwhelmed. Keeping the project branch intact. I'm not modifying any file right now.

**How to create a temporary branch that contain the remaining files ?**

- project
- arch.motorola arch.mips arch.intel
- remaining = whole - parts.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
$ git checkout project
$ git checkout -b remaining
$ git rebase motorola
$ # Fix conflicts.
```

The branch `remaining` should have the differences. However fixing conflicts may be very hard.